# In MicroPython reading memory from attached device via I2C ignores provided address

Tags: arduino, i2c, micropython

I'm trying to translate an [Arduino example project](https://github.com/m5stack/M5StickC-Plus/tree/master/examples/Hat/THERMAL_MLX90640) for the M5 Thermal HAT (using MLX90640) (on an M5StickC) which works for me to MicroPython (1.18).

While trying to read data via I2C strange things happen.

Creating the `I2C` object and scanning the bus with the HAT attached works as expected:

```
>>> from machine import Pin, I2C
>>> i2c = I2C(0, sda=Pin(0), scl=Pin(26), freq=800000)
>>> i2c.scan()
[51]
```

Reading the status register at `0x8000` as described in the [MLX90680 documentation](https://media.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx90640-datasheet-melexis.pdf) also returns data which seems plausible to me:

```
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x8000, 2))
[0, 8]
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x8000, 2))
[0, 9]
```

Bit 3 indicates available data and bit 0 seems to toggle pages.

But now the magic begins.

As I try to read the "control register" at `0x800D` as demonstrated in an [Adafruit example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MLX90640/blob/main/adafruit_mlx90640.py) (and all other examples) it seems to behave exactly like the status register (with a toggling first bit, which should not happen on a control register):

```
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x800D, 2))
[0, 9]
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x800D, 2))
[0, 8]
```

After a bit of experimenting and playing with different addresses and sizes I had to realize that the address provided with [`I2C.readfrom_mem()`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html#machine.I2C.readfrom_mem) seems to be *totally ignored*:

```
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x0000, 16))
[0, 9, 0, 191, 121, 159, 0, 0, 32, 97, 0, 4, 3, 32, 3, 224]
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x1000, 16))
[0, 9, 0, 191, 121, 159, 0, 0, 32, 97, 0, 4, 3, 32, 3, 224]
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x2400, 16))
[0, 9, 0, 191, 121, 159, 0, 0, 32, 97, 0, 4, 3, 32, 3, 224]
>>> list(i2c.readfrom_mem(0x33, 0x2800, 16))
[0, 8, 0, 191, 121, 159, 0, 0, 32, 97, 0, 4, 3, 32, 3, 224]
```

I tried turning all devices off and on again, played with different values for `addrsize` and clock speeds and tried a different HAT attached to the stick (to make sure I2C is working fine in principal) but all with no insights.

Since most code examples (e.g. [this](https://github.com/RevKarl/MLX90640-python/blob/master/MLX90640.py) or [that](https://github.com/m5stack/M5StickC-Plus/blob/master/examples/Hat/THERMAL_MLX90640/MLX90640_I2C_Driver.cpp)) demonstrating how to use the MLX90640 sensor via I2C use low level access to I2C (rather than MicroPythons `readfrom_mem` implementation) I also tried a discrete write/read approach:

```
>>> i2c.writeto(0x33, bytes([0x80, 0x0D]))
2
>>> list(i2c.readfrom(0x33, 2))
[0, 9]
>>> i2c.writeto(0x33, bytes([0x0D, 0x80]))  # try swapped byte order
2
>>> list(i2c.readfrom(0x33, 2))
[0, 9]
```

With all the same effect.

What do I do wrong here? Since I can read data from the I2C bus I guess I don't have a problem of electrical nature.. (also the native Arduino example is fully working on the same device).

Is there some basic I2C knowledge I missed until now?

Why do all I2C `read` operations on this device issued by MicroPython seem to disregard the address while others are working totally fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the **stop** parameter.

[micropython I2C writeto](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html#machine.I2C.writeto)

Try this:

```py
i2c.writeto(0x33, bytes([mem_address>>8, mem_address&0xFF]), False)
i2c.readfrom(0x33, 2)
```

Accordingly to write data  you'd write:

```py
i2c.writeto(0x33, bytes([mem_address>>8, mem_address&0xFF] + [d,a,t,a]))
```

Comment: I wonder what `machine.I2C.readfrom_mem()` is doing differently - I thought this is just what this command is for..